# Convert ISO datetime to local datetime and extract time in c++

Tags: c++, datetime

I have an iso date return from REST api:

`2018-05-07T06:46:24.763Z`

And I want to convert it to local datetime, let say in Philippines, it's +8. So should be

`2018-05-07T14:46:24.763Z`

And I want to extract the time only:

```
14:46
```

And convert it to std::string.

How can I do it?
Do I need to specify the local timezone or is there an automatic getting timezone just like how javascript work in browser?

Thank you.

Comment: look at the boost::date_time library. specifically at the class posix_time and the free functions to do with iso time serialisation/parsing.

Comment: You might want to look into Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), which is making good progress for C++20.

Comment: The `<ctime>` header can help you get localtime from a time epoch.

Comment: I have problem using ctime.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.simple_time_zone

Comment: Which is better? Howard Hinnant's date library or boost library?

Comment: The c++ way would involve using std::chrono, this seems to be the successor of ctime in c++. Converting would just involve adding 8 hours. Mind that std::now() gets a local time.

Comment: @noyruto88, Can't say. Boost's has been around as a solid choice for years. Howard's is on track for standardization and has been favourably viewed all around, but it's less mature. It depends on what you value for your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), here is what it could look like:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string
time_in_philippines(const std::string& utc)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    istringstream in{utc};
    sys_time<milliseconds> tp;
    in >> parse("%FT%TZ", tp);
    auto zt = make_zoned("Asia/Manila", tp);
    return format("%H:%M", zt);
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << time_in_philippines("2018-05-07T06:46:24.763Z") << '\n';
}
```

This program outputs:

```
14:46
```

`sys_time<milliseconds>` is just a `chrono::time_point` based on `chrono::system_clock`, but with `milliseconds` precision.  The `parse` function will parse the `time_point` out of the istream using the indicated parsing flags.

The `time_point` is implicitly UTC.  To convert it to a `zoned_time<milliseconds>` one pairs the UTC `time_point` with a `time_zone` ("Asia/Manila" in this example).  If your computer's current local time zone is already "Asia/Manila", one could also pick up the current time zone with:

```
    auto zt = make_zoned(current_zone(), tp);
```

Next one just formats the `zoned_time` with the desired flags, "%H:%M" in this case.  `format` returns a `std::string`.

Some [installation is required](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation) for working with the time zone library.

Comment: @noyruto88 Yes.  The "installation is required" link gives full instructions for VS.  VS-2015 or later is required.  It consists of 1 source file that needs to be compiled.  And Windows also requires manual installation of curl and 7-zip, or you will need to manually download two database files.  See the section titled "Windows specific:" in the installation instructions.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Do you have tutorial for the installation of this library?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.  But if you have specific questions about it, I'm happy to help.  I'm glad to answer them here, or on the [date gitter chat page](https://gitter.im/HowardHinnant/date?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge).

Comment: Hi Sir, is it possible to get the timezone using this library wherever location. Like if this application will be used in japan, the application will get the timezone for japan, and if it used in philippines, the timezone in philippines will get. Is that possible. Like detecting automatically is timezone? Thank you.

Comment: @noyruto88:  Yes.  Use of `current_zone()` detects the computer's currently set time zone.